# Get MethodInfo of Count() LINQ extension method on arbitrary IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, count, iqueryable

I have IQueryable< T> source and i want to dynamically call IQueryable< T>.Count().

So, i need MethodInfo of Count method declared in IQueryable.

this is its signature (in IQueryable<>) from msdn:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source
)
```

This is how far i got:

```
Expression expr; //this is expression which holds my IQueryable<T>
MethodInfo mi = expr.Type.GetMethod("Count", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { expr.Type }, null);
```

but my mi is always null;

I also tried:

```
mi = typeof(IQueryable<>).GetMethod("Count", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { expr.Type }, null);
```

but again null.

My final goal would be:

```
Expression.Call(mi, expr);
```

UPDATE:
this is how I get Sum Extension method:

```
MethodInfo sum = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Sum", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(IQueryable<decimal>) }, null);
```

and this works, but this Sum method is not generic. It is though static.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to crack out the generic argument of the `IQueryable<T>` type and use that; also the type that owns the method is not `IQueryable<T>`, it is [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx) - if you think about it - interfaces can't have static methods (well, as a commenter has pointed out, in C# that is) :).

Also, because it's a generic method you can't match the parameters in the way you've tried: because you need to pass the generic type *definition* `IQuerable<TSource>` - **not** a generic *type* `IQueryable<int>` or whatever the actual expression is.

Instead you can just look for a single-parametered version of a static method called 'Count' on the `Queryable` type:

```
Type genericArgument = expr.GetGenericArguments()[0];

MethodInfo countMethod = typeof(Queryable)
              .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
              //narrow the search before doing 'Single()'
              .Single(mi => mi.Name == "Count"
                         // this check technically not required, but more future proof
                         && mi.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                         && mi.GetParameters().Length == 1)
              .MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);

//now you can bind to 'countMethod'
```

***Update 7th March 2017*** - Clearly, something changed in the framework which stopped the original version of the code example from working - this is an updated version which should work

Going into it a bit further - the signature of the method is:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(
  this IQueryable<TSource> source
)
```

So while the parameter type is `IQueryable<TSource>` it's generic over the `TSource` type - hence the reason why you need to fish into your `IQueryable<TSource>` expression and grab it's generic argument.  And you should also be able to see what I mean about the parameter here.

Comment: I tried it but it is still null:
Type type = expr.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
MethodInfo mi = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Count", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { type }, null);

But, if I understand correctly, this last function should return something whatever type(s) I provide as 4th argument, right?

Comment: @MilosMijatovic my initial answer wasn't *quite* right have updated

Comment: Great. Good stuff. Appreciate your effort. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, interfaces can have static methods - just not in C# and it's not CLS Compliant :)

Comment: When I call `typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Count", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>) }, null)` I get null (using `System.Linq` and `System.Reflection`). Did I miss something?

Comment: @EugeneOsovetsky If you've found a solution that you think is better than the solution posted here, then you can post it in your own answer.  It's not appropriate to edit your own solution into other people's answers.

Comment: It's a slight modification to the existing answer. I do not have sufficient understanding of the issue to write a full answer myself, and I don't want to take credit for a slight modification to what's basically someone else's answer. However, I felt that my edit can be very helpful to people that are trying to use this answer and are running into the same issue as I am. I don't see how removing my code snippet helps anyone.

Comment: @EugeneOsovetsky - have updated the example so it now works :)

Answer (score 4):

Let the compiler get the method for you.

```
Type genericArgument = expr.GetGenericArguments()[0];
var fakeExp = (Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>, int>>)(q => q.Count());
var mi = ((MethodCallExpression)fakeExp.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(genericArgument);
```

Comment: When I try Expression countEx = Expression.Call(propEx, mi); it gives me error: Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: instance

Comment: Use the overload that takes the MethodInfo as the first parameter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Count is a static extension method in the System.Linq.Queryable class ;)

Comment: Cheeeeeers!! Now it works! Thanks, bro! I'd prefer this as an answer, because this one is more clear to me.